# Form works in Chrome and IE but not firefox

Tags: php, html, forms

I created a form which works in Chrome and IE, but not Firefox. On submit, it simply goes to a blank screen with the URL of my PHP file, `sendContact.php`.

Here's the markup:

```
<form action="script/sendContact.php" method="post" class="contactForm">
  <div class="textBoxDivs">
    <label>Name</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="40" class="textField"/>
  </div>
  <div class="textBoxDivs">
    <label>Phone</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" size="40"class="textField"/>
  </div>
  <div class="textBoxDivs">
    <label>Email</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="40"class="textField"/>
  </div>
  <div class="textArea">
    <label>Please describe what services you will require and your proposed budget.</label>
    <br />
    <textarea id="message" cols="40" rows="7" name="message" class="textAreaField">    </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="formButtonDiv">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="formBut"/>
    <input type="reset" value="reset" class="formBut" />
  </div>
</form>
```

and the PHP is as follows:

```
$name       = $_POST['name'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$message    = $_POST['message'];
$phone      = $_POST['phone'];
$formcontent= "From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n Message: $message";
$recipient  = "al@gmail.com";
$subject    = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $userEmail \r\n";

if (mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader, $email))
{
  header ("Location: thankYou.html");
} else {
  echo "mail was not sent";
}
```

Comment: I can submit the page using Firefox (14.0.1) with out issue, and of course php is server-side, it does not know what a browser is.

Comment: Works fine for me in FF14, although obviously I don't know if you're actually getting the emails.

Comment: Strange. Sorry for the false question then, but thanks for the free tests!

Comment: Free? the bill is in the mail :-)

Comment: I'll compensate your services with a good laugh.  I discovered that the form wasn't posting because I was unknowingly attempting to submit it via the page on my hard drive that I had left open and not the one on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried on Firefox right now, and every thing went fine. By the way, looking at your php code, you should check if the form is ok before sending it. I've tried with empty field and I guess you just receive a mail from nobody..

Try something like:

```
$name       = trim($_POST['name']);
$email      = trim($_POST['email']);
$message    = trim($_POST['message']);
$phone      = trim($_POST['phone']);

$formcontent= "From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n Message: $message";
$recipient  = "alverdeja88@gmail.com";
$subject    = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $userEmail \r\n";

if (!empty($name) 
  && !empty($email)
  && !empty($message)
  && mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader, $email))
{
  header ("Location: http://www.dukecitygrafx.com/thankYou.html");
}
else
{
  echo "mail was not sent";
}
```

Comment: Yea, I haven't placed a validator on the form yet.  Sort of on a marathon today!  I will probably put one on tomorrow though.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the new Line in your html file (form Tag!). Firefox could have problems to solve this!
2. Try a `die("hello");` in your sendContact.php

So you can check whether your script will be loaded

```
<?php 
die("hello");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$phone = $_POST ['phone'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "alverdeja88@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $userEmail \r\n";
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader, $email)) {
  header ("Location: http://www.dukecitygrafx.com/thankYou.html");
  die();
} else {
  echo "mail was not sent";
}
?>
```

Comment: Lol, that extra line was actually a transcription error.  It's only in the post and not the code.

Comment: Uh, Case closed then.  How do I end this thread? Haha, it's late o.O

Comment: @AlfonsoVerdeja you can accept an answer to mark the question as *closed* or answer your own question and mark your answer as accepted